# Updating number of displayed elements per page with a drop-down list in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have numerous data displayed in a table, let's say a long list of Students, so I set up a paging feature to display the elements by pages via the PagedList NuGet package. Its use is detailed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application#add-paging-to-the-students-index-page

The number of elements displayed per page is hard-coded : please see in link a few lines below the header, in *Add Paging Functionality to the Index Method* sub-section :

```csharp
// Method for sorting and displaying Students
public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
{

   ...

   int pageSize = 3;
   int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
   return View(students.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

I'd like to put a drop-down list in my view, so that I could directly choose the number of elements to display per page :

[image: Drop-down list so select number of elements per page]

I tried to use a DropDownList HTML helper in my view :

```
@Html.DropDownList("NbElementsPerPageChosen", (SelectList)ViewBag.listNbElementsPerPage)
```

I populate the drop-down list with a SelectList in my controller, but I can't manage to update the data as I select a value.

```csharp
List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "10", Value = "0", Selected = true });
items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "25", Value = "1" });
items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "50", Value = "2" });
items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "100", Value = "3" });
items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "All", Value = "4" });
ViewBag.listNbElementsPerPage = items;
```

I guess I shall access the selected value from the controller and put that accessed value into the pageSize variable. Is it somehow possible to do that ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OK I've managed to code the feature! I even managed to include a jQuery script that makes the page size update whenever the drop-down list has a new selected value.

Using the following tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application, I also added a search feature: submitting a string in a search form (a textbox) allows to filter my tab entries.

However, changing the page size by selecting a new value in the drop-down list **after** having done a search doesn't work: the the search results are reset, all the entries being displayed instead. I guess I forgot to pass some parameter somewhere but I just can't figure out where...

Here is my updated controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page, int? PageSize)

    // Sort order is passed to view in order to keep it intact while clicking in another page link
    ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;

    // Ascending or descending sorting by first or last name according to sortOrder value
    ViewBag.LastNameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "lastname_desc" : "";
    ViewBag.FirstNameSortParm = sortOrder == "firstname" ? "firstname_desc" : "firstname";

    // Not sure here
    if (searchString == null)
    {
        searchString = currentFilter;
    }

    // Pass filtering string to view in order to maintain filtering when paging
    ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

    var users = from u in _db.USER select u;

    // FILTERING
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        users = users.Where(u => u.lastname.Contains(searchString)
                              || u.firstname.Contains(searchString)
    }

    // Ascending or descending filtering by first/last name
    switch (sortOrder)
    {
    case "lastname": // Ascending last name
        users = users.OrderBy(u => u.lastname);
        break;
    case "lastname_desc": // Descending last name
        users = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.lastname);
        break;
    case "firstname": // Ascending first name
        users = users.OrderBy(u => u.firstname);
        break;
    case "firstname_desc": // Descending first name
        users = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.firstname);
        break;
    default:
        users = users.OrderBy(u => u.lastname);
        break;
}


// DROPDOWNLIST FOR UPDATING PAGE SIZE
int count = _db.USER.OrderBy(e => e.Id).Count(); // Total number of elements

// Populate DropDownList
ViewBag.PageSize = new List<SelectListItem>() {
    new SelectListItem { Text = "10", Value = "10", Selected = true },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "25", Value = "25" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "50", Value = "50" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "100", Value = "100" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "All", Value = count.ToString() }
};

int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
int pageSize = (PageSize ?? 10);
ViewBag.psize = pageSize;

return View(users.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

And my Index.cshtml view:

```html
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () { // Submit pageSizeForm when another pageSize value is selected
    $("#pageSize").change(function () {
        $("#pageSizeForm").submit();
    });
});
</script>

@model PagedList.IPagedList<AfpaSIPAdmin.Models.USER>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Users management";
}

<h1>Users management</h1>

<!-- Creating a new entry in table -->
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create new user", "Create")
</p>


<!-- Filtering table entries -->
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Users", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "filterForm" }))
{
    <p>
        Filter: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, new { @placeholder = "First or last name..." })
        <input type="submit" value="Apply"/>
    </p>
}

<!-- Display table -->
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Last name", "Index", new {
                sortOrder = ViewBag.LastNameSortParm,
                currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter
            })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("First name", "Index", new {
                sortOrder = ViewBag.FirstNameSortParm,
                currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter
            })
        </th>
        <th style="min-width: 170px"></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
           <td style = "min-width: 150px">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.lastname)
            </td>
            <td style = "min-width: 150px">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.firstname)
            </td>

            <td> <!-- Using images as buttons for actions -->
                <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Users", new { id = item.Id })" title="Edit">
                    <img src="~/Content/images/edit.gif" />
                </a>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Users", new { id = item.Id })" title="Details">
                    <img src="~/Content/images/info.gif" />
                </a>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Users", new { id = item.Id })" title="Delete">
                    <img src="~/Content/images/delete.gif" />
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

<br/>

<!-- Paging -->
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Users", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "pageSizeForm" }))
{
    <div class="pager">
        Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) sur @Model.PageCount<br/>

        @Model.Count of @Model.TotalItemCount elements 

        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new {
            page,
            sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort,
            currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter,
            searchString = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, pageSize = ViewBag.psize
        }))

        <!-- DropDownList for setting page size -->
        Elements per page :
        @Html.DropDownList("pageSize")
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably simplest to pass the page size as a parameter to the controller in addition to the page number, and have everything else pretty much the same.

Comment: How would you do that exactly?

Comment: Add a new parameter to the Index() method, called let's say pageSize, and use it instead of the hard-coded value. You can also set a default on it. Then pass its current value when generating the links. You'll probably also want some javascript to reload the page with the correct parameter when the selected value changes in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Include @Html.DropDownList inside a Form and add a submit button. When the user selects a value and post it to the controller, save it in Session and use this value in all controllers.

Comment: How do I post it to the controller?

Comment: @DamianTaylor That's a really basic question, I suggest you should read some Asp.Net book...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/controller-methods-views